# TypeScript: How do I narrow / write a guard for a complex conditional type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, conditional-types, typeguards

Given the following `MultiselectValue`  conditional type, how do I make it resolve to either `LabeledValue<T>` or `Array<LabeledValue<T>>` based on the value of `multiple` or via a guard inside `Comp`?

```js
export interface LabeledValue<T = unknown> {
  label: string;
  value: T;
}

export type MultiselectValue<T, Multiple> = Multiple extends (undefined | false)
  ? LabeledValue<T>
  : Array<LabeledValue<T>>;

export type MultiselectProps<T, Multiple extends boolean | undefined> = {
  multiple: Multiple;
  value: MultiselectValue<T, Multiple>;
}

Comp({
  multiple: true,
  value: [{ // tsc complains if not an array (as expected) because 'multiple' is 'true'
    label: 'Option 1',
    value: 5
  }]
});

function Comp<T, Multiple extends boolean | undefined = undefined>(props: MultiselectProps<T, Multiple>) {
  const { multiple, value } = props;

  if (multiple) {
    // value is an arrray here
  } else {
    // value is a string here
  }
}
```

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgGUwCNgAbYAEwDVNSBXYAHgBU4BeOOpAayQgHckAPjgBvAFBw4pYmQBccAM4woyAOYBuSXAButBguZaAvuPGhIsODACeYPAFk6pGAkVlg2GDXpNmAGjgnFwQwchEOYNcwvFBUJApFOAAKLgpgdGRKOAAfOCxSdwBKbQB%20Allyan0-IW0FAEEoKEwbRkISKp8GFiEhLXNwaHhbeyDnV3dyLwAFKAgwRRZAqNDyODjgBKSiCAhyTCRczgSMrIoIsW0AWwm14AVVmK0pPV9Hu6nPbxrl8ZCYv1xKZxABhCDXMDJCRSW4A8gKFQMfzaN4GOAAbVEcAA9DjrIpsHBsBCwphkEkEOg4Hx4Ic4Jhmq1tFIZJ0FAByADyYFcECOAEYOSipK8agoAKzaYwAXWBRQG6C4XgQ-Lg4Mhfye6022zgu32wHpeTSZyQ2Q4psy5ouyTA80WHxCX1mDqWAX%200XCRSuUhJSGUYjgcK9wECaLwxnYcHtC0UAykVJSIfuPphorxuhqiCS9MZTJscAAFmhgNKNoU8OmpJmIzmGUoVOpi6XpcCgA)

EDIT: [non-generic version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgGUwCNgAbYAEwDVNSBXYAHgBU4BeOOpAayQgHckAPjgBvAFBw4pYmQBccAM4woyAOYBuSXAButBguZaAvuPEB6c3BgALBIusBPMHj7wkwSpTiYkjgLbQwOKgkLBOLnAAsnSkMPZkwNgwNPRMzAA00bHxYOQiHDFxCHl4oKhIFA4AFFwUwOjI3gA%20cFikisAAlNoA-ASy5NT66ULaCgCCUFCYjoyEJEOpDCxCQloh4NDwMM54RfGd5MkAClAQYIqr7GLa-jkl5ArtnVpSemkKC4nDaasmcFaEik92KpQUKgYb10I0m01m80GlGWo3W4mMGwAwhB-GBqsC4KDck9rFAGBltB8DHAANqiOCWayKbBwbA4vKYZAOBDoOBuHxIHzwxzaKQyRYKADkAHkwPEIIKAIySilSd6wuAAVm0xgAuuiuht0FxkggFXBsbjVtUwOdLgoDgljjAzhcrswhF1blI2UhlGJCQ9SlkqXhjDdbW6NlIeXBqkTHt1vWrGaHEA5fELhXAbGhgmqYWkLFY4AA9Xo6uBkTrJqSpkbpnxKFTqHN50WFhjFqTlnXooA) of the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to actually change the definition of `MultiselectProps`:

```
type MultiselectProps<T, Multiple extends boolean | undefined> = Multiple extends (undefined | false) ? {
  multiple: Multiple;
  value: LabeledValue<T>;
} : {
  multiple: Multiple;
  value: Array<LabeledValue<T>>;
};
```

Now, in the function body, `props` is a discriminated union (unresolved type), which means you can narrow it like you already have done.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAQA1m)

Comment: Thanks! I've also added the non-generic version of your answer to my question.